# Tagging for printer specific brand and type

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, tagging

If you look at the existing tags there are tags for printer brands/types and tags for mechanical 3D printer types (e.g. Delta or Prusa, which actually is a brand and a mechanical type...).

Do we need to create tags for every printer out there or list them by type?

My reasoning for creating tags for all brands/types is that people that have a problem with their printer search on their printer brand/type and the problem. E.g. people with an Anet A2 will most likely not search for "Display of my Prusa i3 clone is not working, help!", I rather think it contains the "Anet A2 in the phrasing". I do however think that that we should create synonyms to the mechanical type like Prusa, Delta, CoreXY, Cartesian.

Please share your ideas and suggestions in the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I think I see, and I may have initially misunderstood.  I had understood (in the chat) that you wanted a tag for *each* make/model, but, in fact, you would rather link each make/model back to a printer type, so

```
P3Steel -> Prusa
Kossel -> Delta
```

Is that right?

If so, then I am not so sure. I would want to keep some of the [p3steel](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/p3steel) questions to be specific to P3Steel and not just general [prusa](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prusa) issues.

Likewise, some [kossel](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kossel) issues are specific to the Kossel and not to all [delta](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta) printers.

In some cases I would agree that your reasoning is correct, but not in all cases. In the cases where you are right (such as the example that you cite), then the question would just need retagging correctly, but not require linking all of a particular printer's make/model related questions (via the *synonym-ising* (?) of the tag) back to that particular printer's type.

Does that make sense? Have I understood correctly?

As an example, if you have a generic question about a ANet A2 printer, that actually concerns *all* cartesian printers, but especially Prusa, you would have to manually tag that question [aneta2](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aneta2) and [prusa](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prusa) and [cartesian](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cartesian), so that it gets grouped in such a way, where Cartesian, Prusa and AnetA2 are subsets of the previous (super)set. I don't think you can internally link the tags, if you see what I mean, that mechanism doesn't exist.

Likewise, if you have a generic question about a ANet A2 printer, that actually concerns *all* prusa printers (but *not necessarily* all cartesian printers), you would have to manually tag that question [aneta2](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aneta2) and [prusa](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prusa) and *maybe* [cartesian](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cartesian).

Comment: Actually I meant both, but I can see now what you mean. So let's make tags for all printers (e.g. AnetA2 is not there, but we have specific questions for them) and I thought that we could also link AnetA2 tag to e.g. Prusa as it is a Prusa clone printer or maybe better `cartesian` (e.g. mech. types are Cartesian, Delta, SCARA and Polar). Maybe I misunderstood the synonyms, but I thought of it as mathematical collections, so AnetA2 is a type of a collection Cartesian, but I'm beginning to understand that it is just rewording, correct?

Comment: I don't think that the tagging works like that. You would have to manually tag that question [AnetA2] and [Prusa] and (maybe) [cartesian], so that it gets grouped in such a way, like using sets, and subsets. I don't think you can *internally* link the tags, if you see what I mean, that mechanism doesn't exist.

Comment: So basically the answer is that we need tags for every printer brand/type, and if the problem is more mech. type specific, we also need to add that?

Comment: Yeah, that's right :-)

Comment: done, I've put two examples